# strip_tags|truncate:150 only return a few chars

Tags: php, html, smarty, truncate, strip-tags

I have job search page which display all jobs with its first 150 chars from jobdescription:

```
{$listing.JobDescription|strip_tags|truncate:150} in smarty php template file
```

will return:

```
Responsibilities:  1) Handle...
```

and this is what source code for the above:http://jsfiddle.net/e2ScF/126/
.

Original text built from editor and sample text is at: http://jsfiddle.net/e2ScF/125/

My question is how to make job search result display without < p >,< br/ > and others html tag like:

```
Responsibilities:1) Handle outbound telesales campaigns for consumer markets (for CallMark clients) by...
```

Comment: Truncate also cuts html tags. It's not just cutting text content.

Comment: Will it calculated cutted html like at http://jsfiddle.net/e2ScF/126/ or why this happen?

Comment: Maybe you should `|trim` (or otherwise cut down the whitespace) before trunacting

Comment: I added |trim|strip_tags|truncate:150 or |strip_tags|trim|truncate:150 but nothing change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that there are a lot of whitespaces in the middle of the text, so truncate counts them in the 150 limit.

Try with  [strip](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.strip.tpl):

```
{$listing.JobDescription|strip_tags|strip|truncate:150}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a PHP example ([See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/k7SFjy)):

```
<?php
    $string = '<p>
    &nbsp;</p>
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" class="normalword" style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" width="95%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table align="center" border="0" bordercolor="#666666" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" class="normalword" width="100%">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div align="justify">
                                    Responsibilities:&nbsp;<br />
                                    <br />
                                    1) Handle outbound telesales campaigns for consumer markets (for CallMark clients) by utilizing effective presentation and creating positive relationship for all customer contacts with the aim to cross/up selling client&rsquo;s product and services.&nbsp;<br />
';

function firstXChars($string, $chars = 100)
{
    $string = trim(strip_tags($string));
    $string = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $string);
    preg_match('/^.{0,' . $chars. '}(?:.*?)\b/iu', $string, $matches);
    return $matches[0];
}

echo firstXChars($string);
```

Comment: Hi! I clicked "See it in action" and found the output is what I have now... That is : 'Responsibilities:  1) Handle'. Shouldn't char calculate start from Responsibilities but not <p>?